After upgrading from 22.04 to 24.04, the BIOS was flashed, and I am suddenly getting a supervisor password prompt at startup
I just upgraded my Lenovo ThinkPad T460 from 22.04 to 24.04. When the process was finished, I clicked the "restart" button and the computer restarted. Now I am being greeted with a BIOS supervisor password prompt that I have never seen before. I have owned this computer for 3 years. I bought it used (Amazon), but have never been prompted for a BIOS password before.
Details: Upon restart after the Ubuntu upgrade, it popped into a BIOS screen and I saw a progress bar and it beeped every couple of seconds. I wasn't watching closely, so I don't know what was happening, but I did see the word "flash" on the screen.
Now at startup I am greeted by what I think is the supervisor password prompt.
I know I'm kind of out of luck if I don't know this password, but my question is just this: why did this happen? Under what circumstances would an OS upgrade prompt a reflash or something of the BIOS? How can it be that a supervisor password is suddenly required when clearly it was not set before?

I suspect this is the result of running secure boot.
There is a system setup that uses security keys such that only signed executables will run from the first process to the finished running Ubuntu in a chain. This is called secure boot. In order for this to work for software built on the system (like a graphics driver) an extra key (actually key pair) is added call the MOKKEY  (Machined Owned Key). One part is used in the software build and the other is stored in the EFI encrypted, (the booting source or boot start point). Only software separated from the OS has access to the top key in the chain and hence all the keys below it which in this instance is the BIOS.
The key would have been produced at the end of the install and a further password would have been added for a successful transfer of the key from the OS to the BIO during a boot.
The point of this is that the person installing has to be physically present by the computer to do it.

Having said that the BIOS password may have been reset before it was sold. You could try just a return? If not I think you might need to reflash or reset (?) the BIOs but I think you would loose the top key so you will loose effectively all the keys underneath it. You should still be able to boot but you will have to turn off the secure boot in the BIOs or rebuild the keychain.
The primary function of a UEFI reset is just to remove the PK (Platform Key). The PK is the outermost "lock" that prevents other Secure Boot keys from being changed, so with it removed you're allowed to freely change KEK/db/dbx entries – or to install a custom PK.
Although the EFI variables related to Secure Boot (db, KEK, PK) may be wiped out, the UEFI also has "backup" ones (dbDefault, KEKDefault, etc.) which are read-only and will always have their original values. This lets you or the firmware restore to its original state with Microsoft+OEM keys even if those are wiped out. (Not sure about the Ubuntu key though.)
It would be worth talking to the manufacturer.
